# Appium inspector is not able to locate iOS app custom objects

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium to automate a iOS mobile app, for few elements, Appium inspector is not able to locate XPATH.

I have read that this is because Appium uses Instruments and that can only locate iOS standard objects but not custom objects.

I appreciate any suggestion/help on this.

Example: Need to locate XPATH for radio button in following

[image: app page screen]

Comment: Have you looked at the accessibility of the custom objects? Do they work with VoiceOver?

Comment: VoiceOver can be enabled in Settings.app -> General -> Accessibility -> VoiceOver, but may be tricky to disable. I ask because Appium uses the same functionality to know about the app as VoiceOver does.

Comment: @Mats I just checked with VoiceOver, it is also not able to identify radio button

Answer (score 1):

Setting the **Accessibility Identifier** to each element would solve the issue.

You can do it in Interface builder or programatically

```
view.AccessibilityIdentifier = "CreditCardTextField";
```

You don't have to use **xpath** you can just use this as **id** for the view.